# SQL Inner Join AND

Tags: sql

i'm having some trouble with an SQL Query...

```
SELECT 
    s.searchword AS searchword, 
    s.id AS id, 
    COUNT( c.id ) AS searchresult, 
    s.region AS region 

    FROM search_words AS s 

    INNER JOIN company_data AS c ON 
    c.text LIKE CONCAT(  '%', s.searchword,  '%' ) 

    AND c.region = s.region 

    GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

RESULT

[{"searchword":"wholesale","searchid":"416","searchresult":"31","region":"stockholm"},{"searchword":"Business","searchid":"329","searchresult":"1","region":"stockholm"},{"searchword":"Hospital","searchid":"330","searchresult":"1","region":"stockholm"},{"searchword":"Transportation","searchid":"337","searchresult":"4","region":"stockholm"},{"searchword":"Electronic","searchid":"334","searchresult":"4","region":"stockholm"},{"searchword":"Cars","searchid":"338","searchresult":"3","region":"stockholm"},{"searchword":"Food","searchid":"340","searchresult":"11","region":"stockholm"},{"searchword":"Retail","searchid":"342","searchresult":"8","region":"stockholm"},{"searchword":"Leasing","searchid":"343","searchresult":"1","region":"stockholm"}]

The problem here is...the region column has an empty value for all regions. 
I need to collect these too... As you can see, it only collects stockholm.

So I was thinking something like...

```
    SELECT 
    s.searchword AS searchword, 
    s.id AS id, 
    COUNT( c.id ) AS searchresult, 
    s.region AS region 

    FROM search_words AS s 

    INNER JOIN company_data AS c ON 
    c.text LIKE CONCAT(  '%', s.searchword,  '%' ) 

    AND c.region = s.region OR s.region = '' 

    GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

But it doesnt work :(

Comment: "*Doesn't work*" is not a valid error message in any DBMS out there. What exactly is the error? And which DBMS do you use? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Including records, which do not meet the `JOIN` criterion, is usually being done using `OUTER JOIN`s instead of `INNER JOIN`s. Could you provide table structure, and sample data in a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)? And the expected output? Which version of which database system are you using?

Comment: a_horse, sorry do not know what DBMS is, this is in php and i use mysql.
Sorry perhaps I should have added this question to MySql.

Comment: abecee, well i'm not that good joins at all. Perhaps I will add some more info if no one else can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Empty "values", or `null`s, in SQL aren't real values - they are the lack thereof, and need to be handled explicitly by the `is` operator. Additionally, `and` has a higher precedence than `or`, so you should have all the conditions handling the `region` in brackets:

```
SELECT 
    s.searchword AS searchword, 
    s.id AS id, 
    COUNT( c.id ) AS searchresult, 
    s.region AS region 
FROM search_words AS s 
INNER JOIN company_data AS c ON 
           c.text LIKE CONCAT(  '%', s.searchword,  '%' ) AND
           (c.region = s.region OR s.region IS NULL)
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you region can be `NULL` or `''` (empty value), this is the bullet proof way to check:

```
COALESCE(s.region, '') = ''
```

This way you replace `NULL` with `''` before comparing to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided so far, you might want to try along

```
SELECT 
    s.searchword AS searchword, 
    s.id AS id, 
    COUNT( c.id ) AS searchresult, 
    IFNULL(s.region, 'all') AS region 
    FROM search_words AS s 
    INNER JOIN company_data AS c
      ON IFNULL(s.region, 'all') = IFNULL(c.region, 'all')
      AND c.text LIKE CONCAT(  '%', s.searchword,  '%' ) 
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 4
    ORDER BY s.date DESC
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfae1b/2).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail. In particular, feel free to adjust the SQL Fiddle (and provide the link to the updated version).